# Webpack cannot import images

Tags: webpack, es6-modules

I am trying to use webpack for importing images. Like this:

```js
import img from '../assets/bmo.png';
```

But I keep getting the error:

> module not found: '../assets/bmo.png'

I have tried all kinds of different paths to the image:

```js
import img from '../assets/bmo.png';
import img from '../../assets/bmo.png';
import img from './assets/bmo.png';
import img from './src/assets/bmo.png';
```

Imports of other files **do** work:

```js
import { GameOver } from "./scenes/game-over";
```

My folder structure:

```
index.html
-src
  -scenes
      game-over.ts
  -assets
      bmo.png
-dist
      bundle.js
```

Why can't I use `import` to import images?

**EDIT**

Webpack config:

```js
var path = require('path');
var pathToPhaser = path.join(__dirname, '/node_modules/phaser/');
var phaser = path.join(pathToPhaser, 'dist/phaser.js');
    
module.exports = {
  entry: './src/game.ts',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.ts$/, loader: 'ts-loader', exclude: '/node_modules/' },
      { test: /phaser\.js$/, loader: 'expose-loader?Phaser' },
      { test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/, use: [{loader: 'file-loader', options: {
          outputPath: 'images',
      } }]}
    ]
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, './'),
    publicPath: '/dist/',
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    port: 8080,
    open: true
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
    alias: {
      phaser: phaser
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: are you using `file-loader` to pull in images?  Can you share your webpack.config?  re: https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-management/#loading-images

Comment: Yes, I just added the webpack config

Comment: Hmm, I'm not seeing any glaring issues.  Ref `import img from './assets/bmo.png';` should work for the import.  Sorry I'm not more help...

Comment: Me neither! It’s not just a harmless ide warning, webpack really won’t compile the project.